# Extract clob postgres value in psql command

Tags: postgresql, psql

With theses row in my table :

[image]

From intellij, when I run my PSQL request, lo_get result is correctly return (here a JSON content)

```
Select lo_get(cast(my_col as bigint)) from my_table
```

my_column is "text" format

But when i execute the same request in psql console on my postgres server, the result is not correctly return

> example :
> \x7b22646174654c6976726169736f6e223a22323032322d30322d32325432333a30303a30302e3030302b30303030222c22666f726d617443616e74696e6573223a5b5d2c226d6f6e74616e7450616e696572456e436f757273223a307d

Is there a way to get these value in psql columns ?

Comment: Why are you casting to bigint if the column is text?

Comment: I found this request with cast in bigint in internet and it's ok on intelliJ ... but not in psql console .... lo_get seems to wait for bigint (without I have [42883] ERROR: function lo_get(text) does not exist Indice : No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.)

Comment: Right but *why* are you casting to bigint. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is a "JSON context"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I encode it in 'escape' method, I get something which looks like JSON, but which doesn't look anything at all like what you show in your image (which does not look like JSON in the least).

```
select encode('\x7b22646174654c6976726169736f6e223a22323032322d30322d32325432333a30303a30302e3030302b30303030222c22666f726d617443616e74696e6573223a5b5d2c226d6f6e74616e7450616e696572456e436f757273223a307d'::bytea,
    'escape');
```

If you want to always encode it like this, you could `set bytea_output TO escape`.  But while that might make sense in the `psql` interactive tool, it probably isn't preferable as a permanent server setting, i.e. when dealing with other clients.

Comment: Thanks, with encode, I can saw my JSON content.